# Diodes question is this correct?

Tags: diodes

We have the diode circuit in the figure. The diodes are real and Vd=0.7 Volt 
I have to find the currents in the diodes and in the resistances R1 and R2
[image]

So I apply KVL in loop 1 and I have

-20+ 0.7+0.7 +I2*5.6=0

Here I find that I2=3.3 mA.This means that the current through D1 is 3.3 mAmper.

I apply KVL to the second loop. -0.7 +3.3*I1=0  so I1=0.212

The current through D2 is I2=I1+Id2 so Id2= I2-I1 =3.088 mA

So the operating point of D1 is (3.3 ; 0.7) and of D2 is (3.088; 0.7)..Is this correct?

Comment: Seems you left out the K ohm, (use 5600 ohm and 3300 ohm).  Also notice that without doing KVL the voltage across R1 is only 0.7v.

Comment: I have made a mistake and written the current as Amper instead of mA .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is problem in your calculations:

> -20+ 0.7+0.7 +I2*5.6=0

Should be:

> -20+ 0.7+0.7 +I2*5600=0

Same with 3,3kOhm resistor - you should use this kind of calculation:

> -0.7 +3300*I1=0

Always remember in all of your calculations to use proper unit.

Comment: Not everything else is OK. The part of "3.3*I1" also needs to change to "3300*I1".

Comment: You have right, but i think author will be smart enough. ;)

Comment: Maybe the original poster would be smart enough. But as stated your answer is wrong. I commented simply to give you the opportunity to correct your answer and make it correct.

Comment: I actually thought about writing the answer in mA,thats why I have written it as 3.3 kohm

Comment: Are the operating points correct?

Comment: You should add units, i think, to the operating points.

Comment: Yeah but I mean,the calculations :(

Comment: They are good. I think. If you want, you can sim this kind of circuits, there are many simulators (also online).

Comment: Yeah, therefore the electronics and power lines guys differ in the Ohm's Law. For the electronics dudes 1A = 1mV/1kOhm while the power line folks say that 1A = 1kV/1mOhm...